# Grails 3.3.8 - how to get session from a service

Tags: grails, grails3

Ok, I have a multimodule project, with the services in a plugin, and multiple web "applicaions" which use it.

The user and player services have a login and register method which needs to "login" the player by updating the session.

This post:[Grails get Session and Management in Service class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062605/grails-get-session-and-management-in-service-class)

Has some solutions, but none actually seem to work. Webutils is not available in any of these locations

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils
import org.grails.web.util.WebUtil
import org.grails.web.util.WebUtils
```

nor does this work:

```
def session = getSession(true)
```

Any suggestions?

This is from build.gradle of the plugin:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:plugin"
    provided "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    provided "org.grails:grails-plugin-domain-class"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
}
```

Comment: "Webutils is not available in any of these locations" - In Grails 3.3.9 `WebUtils does exist at `org.grails.web.util.WebUtils`, however, you shouldn't use it.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions?

Yes.

You can do this:

```
// grails-app/services/somepackage/SomeService.groovy
package somepackage

import grails.web.api.ServletAttributes

class SomeService implements ServletAttributes {

    void someMethod() {
        // you can access the session property directly from here
        println session

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some unknown reason, it cant resolve grails.web.api.ServletAttributes either.  It finds grails.web.api, but not SeverAttributes.  As it cant find org.grails.web.util.WebUtils either, is this something major missing from the project? the services are defined in a plugin.

Comment: `grails.web.api.ServletAttributes` is in `grails-web-common`.

Comment: So is `org.grails.web.util.WebUtils`.

Comment: I see that you changed the Grails version number after I answered the question.  The answer is the same for Grails 3.3.8 as it is for 3.3.9.

Comment: If you can show your build dependencies, that might shed some light on it.  A newly created plugin created with `grails create-plugin ...` should have the necessary dependency.

Comment: The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/johnlittlepluginsession was created with `grails create-plugin johnlittlepluginsession` and I left the default generated `build.gradle` alone.  The service class at https://github.com/jeffbrown/johnlittlepluginsession/blob/591e7b34b4e2a552f58a257734785dd3ee12d836/grails-app/services/somepackage/SomeService.groovy seems fine.

Comment: I dont know how to add grails-web-common as a dependency. I looked at your working project, and tried adding     compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot" but it still cannot resolve grails.web.api.ServletAttributes.  Any idea what I need to add to gradle build file?  I also tried this:     compile "org.grails:grails-web-common" as a guess.

Comment: @JohnLittle - I can't reproduce the behavior you are describing and some of it doesn't make sense to me.  If I could see a sample project that demonstrates the issue it would be trivial to troubleshoot but without that, I don't have any suggestions.  I am sorry that I can't help.  Best of luck.